# Set text as dynamic in a static tableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, text, dynamic

I'm attempting to set my `UILabel` as dynamic text. The `UILabel` appears in a static tableview cell. I have created an outlet for the `UILabel` in my TableViewController and then in `viewDidAppear` I attempt to make the label's text dynamic as follows:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    tableView.reloadData()
    myLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)

    myLabel.accessibilityLabel = myLabel.text
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can get my label to display dynamic text. I'm going to try a custom cell with my static table view.

Comment: Do you mean "Dynamic Type", where the font size changes if the user sets the preferred text size in the Settings App?

Comment: Yes, Koen. I think I need to do it via a custom tableviewcell class. I'm just about to try.

Comment: Also make sure that your `UITableViewController` listens to `UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification`

Answer (score 0):

you should set `myLabel.text` property as `myLabel.accessibilityLabel` is for the accesibility purpose

Comment: Doesn't work. I think because it's a static table view.

Comment: no it's not nil. The text appears but it's not dynamic.

Comment: add print(myLabel) in the end of method

Comment: Thanks. Will try after lunch.